# How to analyse CANopen with Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I've got wireshark 2.2.6 running under ubuntu 16.04. I want to analyse canOpen traffic on vcan0.

Following this tutorial
[wireshark wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CANopen)
I have tried entering 'canopen' into the filter bar, but nothing happend.
What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself:
Analyze > Decode As... > Field:Can, Current:canOpen